# ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open layer Failed to execute (RemoveJoin)

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins

I'm trying to remove a join from table and a layer file and am getting the error in the subject line. Tried using "table" as the arcpy.RemoveJoin_managment() argument and got the the same error.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outFC,"layerFC")      

SeqTable = 'S:\\Shared\\RouteSmart\\CO_161_Cleanscapes\\From_Tower\\CLS_XX_Last28DaysTest.xlsx'

arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(SeqTable,"Join_Table")

QF7 = "SVVCCODE"
QV3 = "%T"
WC5 = """ '{}' LIKE '{}' """.format(QF7, QV3)

arcpy.MakeTableView_management("Join_Table", "GarbSeq", WC5)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("GarbSeq", "CUSTID") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = str(row[0]) + "001"


table = arcpy.JoinField_management("layerFC","Address_ID","GarbSeq","CUSTID")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, ["Sequence", "OLDSEQUENCE"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[1]

arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("layerFC")
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 321, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=1)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "N:\Common\Script\Drivers\PrepCleanScapesUpdate.py", line 85, in <module>
    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("layerFC")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5683, in RemoveJoin
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open layerFC
Failed to execute (RemoveJoin).
```

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from a much larger script that you have copy/pasted from. What happens when you run just the code that you have presented?

Comment: There might be an issue with my query strings. Still getting lost with delimiters: QF2 = "Status"
 RV2 = 'M'
 WC2 = " '{}' <> '{}' ".format(QF2, RV2)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layerFC","ADD_TO_SELECTION",WC2)

Comment: I think you need to present just a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that works up to where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by using  arcpy.JoinField_managment which creates a new table instead of joining tables. Therefore RemoveJoin had nothing to remove.